# DELETE api request responds with 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

I have been banging my head the last 4 hours trying to figure why my DELETE request does not work. It returns a 404 not found response. My POST, PUT, and GET all work fine.

I am using Chrome's Postman to do the requests and my url format is:

DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/products/568c39bfba6030c90c36a061

Here is my code.

Server.js :

```
var express = require('express');


var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

var bodyParser =require('body-parser');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

var app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extend: true})); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api')); 

app.listen(3000); 
console.log('API is running on port 3000');
```

Api.js:

```
var express = require('express'); 

var router = express.Router(); 


var Product = require('../models/product');


console.log(Product);


Product.methods(['get', 'post', 'put',' delete']); 

Product.register(router, '/products'); 

module.exports = router;
```

Product.js

```
var restful = require('node-restful'); 

var mongoose = restful.mongoose; 



var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String, 
    sku: String, 
    price: Number
});

module.exports = restful.model('Products', productSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space (`' delete'`) in your your delete method name.

Comment: Bro you are the man! I don't know how I missed that. Thanks so much!